# Brunch, JSDom : Object [ jsdom NodeList ]: contains 3 items has no method 'map'

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, jsdom, brunch

i'm trying to get headless testing working with Ember, Brunch, and JSDom.  I'm using ember-brunch-skeleton to generate the app.

https://github.com/fuseelements/ember-brunch-skeleton

i have all the dependencies installed.

when I try to run 'brunch test' I get the error below.  It seems like I'm missing something fundamental here, but this is my first time using node.js/jsdom/mocha etc.  What am I missing?

```
  TypeError: Object [ jsdom NodeList ]: contains 3 items has no method 'map'
  at getScriptFilesPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/brunch/lib/commands/test.js:62:60)
  at readTestFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/brunch/lib/commands/test.js:80:25)
  at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
  at fs.close     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/brunch/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:90:5)
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

Comment: @c4p stop with the capitalizing edits of my posts.  i want them lower case.

Comment: i should add this is on OSX v10.7.4, node.js v0.8.18

Comment: Sorry, just trying to help... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-users-edit-other-users-posts-to-correct-grammar-and-spelling-problems

Comment: Same problem here using an angularjs skeleton: https://github.com/scoarescoare/angular-brunch-true-north

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this broke with the 0.4.0 version of jsdom. Specifically from the [changelog](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md):

> - Change: NodeLists no longer inconsistently have array methods. Previously, live node lists would have indexOf, while static node lists would have them all. Now, they have no array methods at all, as is correct per the specification.

If you're looking for a quick fix, reverting to jsdom 0.3.4 should do the trick:

```
npm uninstall jsdom
npm install jsdom@0.3.4
brunch test
```

Comment: This fix worked for me as well. I'm pretty new to node and npm. Shouldn't brunch specify jsdom as a requirement for testing and lock it to 0.3.4?

Comment: @simple10 I may be wrong but technically jsdom is a mocha dependency and I think brunch aims to provide tools but also remain agnostic if you want to choose something else

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this by uninstalling `brunch` and installing it again.
It seemed `npm` was using a old installed version.

Just try:

```
npm uninstall brunch -g
npm install brunch -g
npm test

brunch --version # should be 1.5.3
```